# Flutter image_picker don't save origin name

Tags: image, flutter

In my flutter project, I use image_picker to save an image from my device. And I have some problems. After selecting an image from the gallery, it changes its name to something else. How to get the original name from the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need use [Path Package](https://pub.dev/packages/path/install)

add to pubspec.yaml:

```
dependencies:
  path: ^1.7.0
```

And try this:

```
fileName = path.basename(imageFile.path);
```

Code Example:

```
File _storedImage;
Future<void> _takePicture() async {    
    final imageFile = await ImagePicker.pickImage(
        source: Ienter code heremageSource.camera,      
        maxWidth: 600);            
    final fileName = path.basename(imageFile.path);    
    }
```